# Noticeable difference downgrading to Wireless G network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have had HORRIBLE, FRUSTRATING luck with newer routers. I've had 5 different brands and types, they all stopped working, drop connections, slowed down, or are extremely unreliable after a few months/years/weeks. (I know its not my ISP's fault, plugging it in to their box always works just fine)

Without going into details, now I want/need to replace mine again and was thinking about getting the old trusty Linksys WRT54GL, the classic black and blue box everyone seemed to have years ago. They are still for sale on newegg with over 4,000 reviews.

All my devices are capable of using G, and distance will not be a problem, but will there be a difference when playing games on my Xbox One, or downloading things? My download speed has never gone above 500-600 KB/s, so my thinking seems to believe that the transfer speed of the G is still way above my internet speed, so internet related activities won't be affected.

Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: It's an assumption for you and for the rest of us as well.  The best you can do is give it a try and see if you like it.  Not to discredit your experience, but I've deployed many newer routers and while I encounter the normal issues of interference, distance, faulty hardware, etc. I cannot conclude that routers in general became less reliable starting with 802.11n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

600KB/s is very slow. An ideal 802.11G connection gets ~6.5MB/s but you usually cap out at 4-5MB/s in normal circumstances. So if all you care about is connection to the internet G should be fine.

Changing between G, N or AC might help if all your neighbours are using one specific type (like in an appartment block where everyone received the same wireless router). You could also try scanning to see which channels are used and select a different channel for your SSID.

However, if you are using 802.11N on the 2.4Ghz band now and you have interference from some other source switching to G (also on the 2.4Ghz band) will most likely do very little/nothing. Your best bet in that case would be cables,Powerline type devices or switching to the 5Ghz band if your devices support it.

EDIT: If you're up for another new router this is the one I've had the least complaints about: http://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN66U/

Comment: Yeah we have the internet service that connects to cell towers, so its not the best but it works. We aren't in apartments but there are about 10 other networks around us, and I've tried switching the channels a few times, so maybe it is interference, I guess if the G router does the same thing we will look into powerline options, or a 5ghz router. Thanks!